# Why is nvim myfile.txt.gz not decompressing the file anymore?

Tags: neovim

I used to open my `files.txt.gz` files (or `txt.xz`) files directly with nvim.

But it does not work any more for some months.
Both compiled from source, or from Debian package.

What could be the cause ?

Comment: This is provided by a standard plugin [gzip.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim) (see also [:h gzip](https://vimhelp.org/pi_gzip.txt.html)). So I would check your configuration, whether you disabled this plugin

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem seems like a bug related to access rights since it's only when the file is in read only for the user.

For instance, a `sudo chmod a+w myfile.txt.gz` fixes the issue.

The issue is also present when using `view` or `vim -R` to open the compressed file.

Comment: Maybe could you accept the answer to make the question rest :-) If your are user45181 let me know we can ask an administrator to merge yor accounts.